# Columntransformer columns selected for more than one transformer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to transform the columns of a dataframe through the ColumnTransfomer class. To do that I use the [make_column_selector](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.make_column_selector.html) function to assign transformers by specifying a dtype or a pattern. My question is: what will happen if a column falls into more than one of this criteria?.

**Example:**

I specify through make_column_selector that all of the dtypes float should go through an StandardScaler, Additionally I specify that all the columns that have the pattern `binary_*` have to be OneHotEncoded. My `binary_*` column is also a float that it only takes values 0 and 1.

Would this column be transformed twice (one HotEncoding and StandardScaler)? Will it be caught first by the StandarScaler and ignored by the OneHotEncoder?

In short, I want to know if the columns are propagated through the different transformers of the ColumnTransformer or they are left out as they meet the criteria of one of the transfomers.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this myself. The transformers of ColumnTransformer are executed consecutively in a pipeline manner. Any column that meets the criteria established in make_column_selector the transformer will pass through the transformer.

That means that if one column meets the criteria of one or more transformers it will be transformed twice and appended to the resulting dataframe.